# Background graphic not showing

Tags: html, css

My body background is not showing.  It was working fine half an hour ago, I cannot see why it doesn't show in IE 9 or Chrome.  Its displaying fine in the preview in Expression Web 4.

It should look like this >> http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/31/screenshotlrj.jpg/

HTML code:

```
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Chinatown</title>
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="body-1">
    <div id="header">
        <img height="315" src="images/Chinatown-header.png" width="850" />
    </div>
    <div id="title-1">
        <p>We is pleased to announce the launch of our Social Enterprise - Experience Chinatown</p>
    </div>
    <div id="maindescription-1">
        <p>RTE are conducting unique tours to celebrate Chinatown, the beating heart of our culture in.  We will be 
        taking people on a journey through Chinatown on a guided tour about the stories of the locals and pioneers that
        made Chinatown what it is today, and then expanding the experiences with tasting tours of the variety of delicious cuisines
        on offer.  Please see below for more information:</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color:#000;
    background: #9c0000;
}
p {
    margin : 0;
    padding : 0;
}
#body-1 {
    width: 870px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #9c0000;
    background-image: url('images/Chinatown-bg.png');
}
#header {
    padding:10px;
    background:#bc0000;
}
#title-1 {
    font: normal normal bold 100% "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
    float: left;
    width: 850px;
    padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
    color: #FFFF00;
    text-align: justify;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#maindescription-1 {
    font: 100% "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
    float: left;
    width: 850px;
    padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: justify;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Anyone see any problem with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it as -

```
#body-1 {
    width: 870px; height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url('images/Chinatown-bg.png') #9c0000 no-repeat left top;
}
```

EDIT:

It must be hidden there. Try setting some height to the ID -

Check here [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wG3fa/)

Comment: But I want to add more content that's going to be greater than 500px.  Can I have auto height, or something?

Comment: Thanks but auto works fine, unless theres a reason not to use it?

Comment: @TeaDrinkingGeek Define min-height only to make the background image visible if the container has less text.... :)

Answer (score 0):

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/2zj03aMv)***

Hi now define `overflow:hidden;` in your `#body-1` **id**

as like this

```
#body-1 {
   overflow:hidden;
 }
```

***[Live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/kqjQCULZ)***

### ----------------------------

### -----------------------

**Second** is

```
#body-1:after{
content:'';
  clear:both;
  overflow:hidden;
display:block;
}
```

***[Live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/evBRraJg)***

Comment: Overflow: hidden erase all my other content what I want to add below.  e.g.  more <div> with content.

Comment: @TeaDrinkingGeek than used to this #body-1:after{
content:'';
  clear:both;
  overflow:hidden;
display:block;
} and clear your body-1 tag in after and now check to my updated second option ..........

Answer (score -1):

please try  this

```
#body-1 {
    width: 870px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #9c0000 url('images/Chinatown-bg.png')  no-repeat 0 0;
}
```